# Showing Variable's Value on Message Box

Tags: matlab, messagebox, matlab-guide

This is a very simple problem, I have been trying it for some times, but not working.

I have this code:

```
[s,h]=silhouette(cobat,g,'SqEuclidean')

MS = mean(s)

z = [cobat s];
```

I want to show the `MS` value on message box. The message box is going to be like this, 'The result is [here `MS` value will be placed]'

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it the following way:

```
h = msgbox(['The result is ' num2str(MS)], 'Title of the message box')
```

With `num2str` I convert the numerical result to a string, and with the square brackets I concatenate "The result is " with the result to display it in the message box.

Comment: Usually it's better to use `sprintf` instead of `num2str`, for example: `sprintf('The result is %d', MS)`.

Comment: Thank you, Eitan. Can you tell me why should we use `sprintf` better than `num2str`?

Comment: @AlviSyahrin `num2str` is slower, and (in my opinion) complicates the syntax.